# Как преобразовать строку в массив

Tags: python, list, python-3.9

например пользователь ввёл `[1, 2, 3]` в консоль
и как мне из этого сделать список.
пробовал так но не работает

```
array = []
exec("array = " + content)
# print(array)
if array[0] == 1:
   print(1)
```

после exec проверяю массив, а он пустой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понял зачем Вам `exec` здесь нужен. Используете обычный парсинг.

Вариант 1. Через функции строки

```
text = '[1, 2, 3]'    
parse = text.strip('[]').replace(' ', '').split(',')  # список из строковых значений, потом можно преобразовать в нужный формат
```

Вариант 2. Через библиотеку `json`.

```
import json
text = '[1, 2, 3]'
parse = json.loads(text)
```

Вариант 3. Парсим через библиотеку re

```
parse = re.findall('([-+]?\d+)', text)  # Если в строке-списке будут только целые числа
parse = re.findall('([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)', text)  # Если будут еще десятичные
```

Что у Вас получился список можно проверить функцией `type(parse)`, которая выдаст `<class 'list'>`

В первом и третьем варианте на выходе будут списки из строк с числами. Их нужно будет преобразовать.

Comment: спасибо вариант с json больше всего подходит

Answer (score 2):

```
# если content - это уже список
content = [1, 2, 3]
array = []
exec("array.extend(content)")
if array[0] == 1:
    print(1)

# если content - это строка
content = '123'
array = []
exec("array.extend(int(i) for i in content)")
print(array)
if array[0] == 1:
    print(1)

# если content - это строка '[1, 2, 3]'
import re
# имеем строку inp
inp = '[1, 2, 3]'
# забираем цифры в список
content = re.findall('\d+', inp)
array = []
exec("array.extend(content)")
print(array)
if array[0] == 1:
    print(1)
```

Comment: А если это обычный текст со структурой списка

Comment: @Nuvoobchemkak-totak, приведите пример.

Comment: `inp = input("Введите текст: ")    
>>> [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Nuvoobchemkak-totak, ну значит забрать из этой строки цифры. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
string = '[1, 2, 3]'

string = string[1:-1].replace(', ', '')

arr = []

for i in string:
    arr.append(int(i))

print(type(arr))
```

Comment: А если будет [11, 12, 13]?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @AndyPavlov, не продумал. Писал на коленке XD